# AutoCompleteTextView only show one option after dark mode enable

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, material-components-android, materialautocompletetextview

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/auto_complete_text_view"
            android:inputType="none"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

```kotlin
val items = arrayOf("A", "B", "C")
binding.autoCompleteTextView.setSimpleItems(items)
```

I hava an simple exposed dropdown menu like this.

[image]

When I select one of options, and then enable dark mode. It no longer works fine.
As the screenshot shows, I select "A", then enable dark mode. When I was opening the dropdown again to select another option there was only one option in the list ("A").

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set saveEnabled to "false" for the MaterialAutoCompleteTextView in XML

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/auto_complete_text_view"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:saveEnabled="false" />
```

Comment: This does work, but also brings a new problem. The selected value will be cleared.

Comment: You can set text using liveData and MVVM architecture. LiveData will be lifecycle aware and automatically set the value when the screen is live.